# AlarmManager does not work in the same way on every tested device

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm currently developping an app, that need several alarm trigger at the exact time.

For this purpose i created a receiver that schedule the next alarm.
I also created a stress test :

alarmManager call my receiver which create an other alarm for the next minute.
At xx:30 and xx:00 i receive a mail with the log of all the alarm containing the expected date and the triggered date.

All work well on my phone, a samsung galaxy note 3 lite.
Sadly the behavior is not the same on all the devices.

- Huawei Honor :I launched it yesterday at 6PM, it worked until 6:16PM and restarted at 6:45PM before completely stop at 7PM.
- OnePlus 2 : Currently working, but some notification are not triggered, about 20%... that's a lot for what i need...

So i'm wondering, if some devices have an alarmManager that stop some Alarm When it abused of the system. Unfortunately, I did not find enough of Doc to support this theory.
Have you ever had this kind of problem, how do you solved it?
How can you make a system That will Delivered a notification at the right time with a success rate > 95%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and after a lot of searching and workaround, I figured that Smart Manager of Samsung Devices in Lollipop and above may be the problem. This component can delay the Alarm Manager to goes off, it is triggered after 3 minutes, if the mobile is working on battery and with the screen closed. Of course you can deactivate the Smart Manager like this :

- Launch Samsung Smart Manager application on the device
- Tap Battery
- Tap App optimization
- Detail
- Find Your APP
- Select "Disabled for"

But in my case it didn't work, neither disabling the Smart Manager worked in 2 Samsung devices with Lollipop . What it did work was to "fool" Smart Manager by refactoring the name of my application's package to contains the String "alert" or "alarm", for example com.example.alarm.myApplication. You can also refer to this link for more information.

Also some other companies like Huawei have their own optimized app that can delay `AlarmManager` . 
Also the new component `Android Doze` may delay the `AlarmManager` 
Please refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).
Finally your phone works well because is below `Lollipop` and does not contain Samsung's SmartManager.